# Incorrect encoding using PHP as Apache module

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, module, cgi

I have very specific problem running PHP as Apache 2.2 module. When running PHP as CGI, everything works OK, but slow. The output I get in this case is:

[Good charset](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-V-g40oqThdo/Tj-m152yy9I/AAAAAAABN7k/es67gFWN7ZY/good%252520charset.png)

But when runing PHP as Apache module on the same environment, I get the following output:

[Wrong charset](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RPpitrmidS4/Tj-mx6x87kI/AAAAAAABN7o/DgPlyxtIipE/wrong%252520charset.png)

The only difference is that I add following lines to appropriate VirtualHost in httpd.conf

```
SetEnv PHPRC "C:/PHP5/"
ScriptAlias /local-bin/ "C:/PHP5/"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 php
Action application/x-httpd-php5 "/local-bin/php-cgi.exe"
<Directory "C:/PHP5/">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  <Files "php-cgi.exe">
    Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

The website uses 2 databases - one MySQL and one MSSQL. The text which is displayed incorrectly is retrieved from MSSQL database. There aren't any problems with text which is retrieved from MySQL database.
Any ideas how to run PHP as Apache module and get the same output as running PHP as CGI?

My setup is: Apache 2.2; PHP 5.2.17; mssql PHP extension 7.0; mbstring PHP extension 4.4.4

Headers in CGI mode, returned by curl -i

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 11:56:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3h4kpps0l02pecfgktonq7rjd6; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

Headers in PHP as a module mode:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 12:04:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.2.13
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=hi9h3skbsjvpcr7usdlf36d2t7; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Check you PHP configuration, it might differ between the two SAPI types. Look for the `default_charset` ini setting for example.

Comment: php.ini file is used the same in both cases, changing default_charset also has no effect :(

Comment: Check the servers response header with a commandline tool like `curl -i http://yoururl/` and compare if both are the same.

Comment: No, output is not the same. In CGI mode I get correct characters, but changing to PHP as Apache module I get corrupted output. For example: <div class="text">¾￳¾_¾�</div> instead of     <div class="text">Павел Санаев</div>

Comment: I was asking for the response headers, not the response body.

Comment: I've edited my post, see above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was the exact problem, but everything seems to work OK now. I just downloaded fresh PHP package and configured it from scratch. What I didn't mention is that I use ZendServer Community Edition and it seems to cause the problems (by the way with same PHP 5.2.17 version). When I configure virtual host to use my fresh PHP installation - everything works OK, but when I use ZendServer built in PHP it causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to run PHP as Apache module and get the same output as running PHP as CGI?

Normally the output does not differ because of the module type but because of configuration. Just keep the same configuration across SAPI types and you're done.

> The website uses 2 databases - one MySQL and one MSSQL. The text which is displayed incorrectly is retrieved from MSSQL database.

Looks like retrieving from MSSQL fails. Check if the data is properly encoded in the database. Check the client encoding settings. This should solve your issue.

Comment: The configuration is exactly the same, all I change is that I add some lines to enable PHP as CGI to httpd.conf. php.ini is used the same, php directory is also the same. I can't see any differences in phpinfo(); output except of PHP mode. But text in PHP as a module case gets corrupted. It seems that there is some kind of problem not in Apache or PHP configuration but either in mssql or mbstring extensions. I'm giving up...

Comment: The problem is the code/configuration related to your MSSQL database access and/or setup of the MSSQL database and the date therein.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the encoding with the content type, e.g.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This fixes most issues.